# Parentheses and cinoptions, how to make additional indentation?

Tags: vim, rust, indentation

I'm using coc-pairs - which adds additional pair automatically, and because of it i'm using cr, instead of <cr>)O combination - which works, but that's not a point.

Wrong behavior:

```
fn some fn(<cr>)
fn some_fn(
    x: i64
    ) <--- incorrect indentation
```

How to make like that:

```
fn some fn(<cr>)
fn some_fn(
    x: i64
) <--- CORRECT INDENTATION
```

Current options:

```
set cinoptions=L0,(s,Ws,J1,j1,m1
set indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,0[,0],0(,0)
```

Comment: See if doing `:set indentkeys+=0)` helps.

Comment: Nope: set indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,0[,0],0(,0)

Comment: This is not the default value, are you using some third-party Rust plugin?

Comment: Yes, rust.vim, but the default also works same with parentheses.

Comment: You should use their issue tracker, then.

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim!